# In SpriteKit, SKCropNode has no effect over a SKShapeNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've been trying to apply a mask to a SKShapeNode using SKCropNode, and so far without success. Thinking that it's a SpriteKit bug - Here is the code snippet:

```
SKNode* contentNode = [SKNode node];

// picture - use an image bigger than 50x50
SKSpriteNode *pictureNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"tree"];

// triangle
SKShapeNode* triangleNode = [SKShapeNode node];
UIBezierPath* triangleNodeBezierPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[triangleNodeBezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
[triangleNodeBezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 100.0)];
[triangleNodeBezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 100.0)];
[triangleNodeBezierPath closePath];

triangleNode.path = triangleNodeBezierPath.CGPath;
triangleNode.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1];

// create a mask
SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size: CGSizeMake(50, 50)]; //50 by 50 is the size of the mask

// create a SKCropNode
SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];

[cropNode addChild: contentNode];
[cropNode setMaskNode: mask];

[self addChild: cropNode];
[contentNode addChild:pictureNode]; // pictureNode is being cropped
[contentNode addChild:triangleNode]; // triangleNode is not

cropNode.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX (self.frame), CGRectGetMidY (self.frame));
```

Does anyone have a workaround about this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

This had been bugging me for most of the day. I had planned to create a timer similar to the excellent [TCProgressTimer by Tony Chamblee](http://tonychamblee.com/2013/11/18/tcprogresstimer-a-spritekit-progress-timer/). However, as my application uses multiple progress timers I didn't want to have to design dozens of different sized sprites for use at different resolutions.

My solution was to convert `SKShapeNode` objects to `SKSpriteNode` objects. I ended up having to go back to basics and use Core Graphics to do the heavy lifting. This is a rather messy way of doing things, I'm sure, but I wanted quick results to dynamically create objects that would resemble the results obtained when using `SKShapeNode`.

I am only interested in making circle objects at present, so I did it like this:

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)createSpriteMatchingSKShapeNodeWithRadius:(float)radius color:(SKColor *)color {
    CALayer *drawingLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *circleLayer = [CALayer layer];
    circleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,radius*2.0f,radius*2.0f);
    circleLayer.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;
    circleLayer.cornerRadius = circleLayer.frame.size.width/2.0;
    circleLayer.masksToBounds = YES;


    [drawingLayer addSublayer:circleLayer];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(circleLayer.frame.size.width, circleLayer.frame.size.height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), TRUE);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0,0,circleLayer.frame.size.width,circleLayer.frame.size.height));
    [drawingLayer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *layerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:layerImage]];


    return sprite;
}
```

The resulting sprite can now be masked by an `SKCropNode` as expected. As these sprites are all generated before the scene begins, I do not notice a performance hit. However, I would imagine this method is highly inefficient if you are generating multiple nodes on the fly.

I would be eager to hear solutions from other users. Hope that helps.

-DC

Comment: Sigh, I also ran into this problem. I filed a Radar on this. It is pretty unfortunate that SKShapeNode cannot be used with SKCropNode. Fortunately in my case I needed a rectangle, so I could just use SKSpriteNode.

Comment: @MobileBen the inability of CGPaths to have their properties edited, like line editing should be, in both SKShapeNode and CAShapeLayer is one of the most amazing oversights in 2D drawing and animation technologies I've ever seen. And that level of missing the obvious pervades much of SpriteKit's design-by-numbers approach to 2D interactivity, rendering, operation and usage. reminds me of my cooking: A hodgepodge of Bubble-n-Squeak, half baked and served on paper plates; best eaten with a spork.

Comment: @Confused Apple builds generic for the masses to be able to make products. Unfortunately for games, you often have specialized cases. Add to this that the team working on SK are probably not using it to build a game, but only demos. So they don't really understand how all these items will be used in the field. They just seem to have a checklist of features. All part of why I dumped SK. SK performance is actually not great. I also suspect it won't scale well the larger and larger a game gets. Now that I have my newer engine up and running, my game runs a ton faster and dev is easier.

Comment: Perhaps the thing that's missing (at Apple) is a desire to define themselves by gaming and game performance. There's no indication they care or concern themselves with the game market. Success as mobile gaming devices has been (largely) incidental to Apple - a consequence of blending focus on user interaction performance, first mover advantage and brand power attaining a market, and programmers and consumers seeking to scratch their gaming itch.

Answer (score 5):

I have the similar task in my app. I need to draw multiple irregular shapes based on user input and then use them as crop node's masks.

The solution that works for me is to:

1. create a SKShapeNode with the required path
2. retrieve a SKTexture from it using  SKView method `textureFromNode:crop:`
3. create a SKSpriteNode from that texture.
4. use SKSprite node as a mask.

Comment: This is best practice, making me clear what SKView. textureFromNode:crop: is for. ;-)

Comment: I'm having trouble with `textureFromNode:crop:`: it returns `nil` even though the rect I pass is  sensible one. I'm working on an SKShapeNode so there is no size property available; I'm passing a predetermined size for the crop rect. On the other hand, `textureFromNode:` works fine (but the texture is off-center).

Answer (score 2):

Your title is correct.  I've also discovered having a ShapeNode in the CropNode's hierarchy affects the children above it as well.  I created a quick experiment.  You can create a new game project and try it yourself.  By commenting out one of the addChild:shapeContent lines you can see how it affects the cropping of the spaceship image.

As DoctorClod points out the current solution seems to be making sure all children of the cropNode are SpriteNodes.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

SKSpriteNode* colorBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(800, 600)];

SKSpriteNode *spaceshipImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

SKShapeNode* shapeContent = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
shapeContent.fillColor = [SKColor greenColor];

SKSpriteNode *maskShape  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(500, 100)];

SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode new];

[cropNode addChild:colorBackground];
[cropNode addChild:shapeContent];     // comment this one out
[cropNode addChild:spaceshipImage];
[cropNode addChild:shapeContent];     // or comment this one out

[cropNode setMaskNode:maskShape];

cropNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX (self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:cropNode];
}
```