# SKCropNode fails when I add extra SKNode children in hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, skcropnode

**Update: It looks like iOS 10 has fixed this issue. I upgraded to Swift 3 and Xcode 8 and everything is working as expected.**

---

I've run into this issue a couple times now and I can't tell if it's a bug in SKCropNode or if I'm just misusing it. Perhaps there's some bit of documentation I'm missing to explain why this is happening?

---

I have a crop node with a 100x100 rectangle shape as the mask. If I place a blue circle inside it, it gets cropped properly.

```
// Create a crope node with a small square.
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
let cropNodeMask = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
cropNodeMask.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
cropNode.maskNode = cropNodeMask
self.addChild(cropNode)

// Create a blue circle and put it in the crop node.
let blueCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 110)
blueCircle.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
blueCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cropNode.addChild(blueCircle)
```

[image]

---

Now, when I place that same circle inside of an otherwise empty SKNode and place that container inside the same crop node, cropping fails.

```
// Create a crope node with a small square.
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
let cropNodeMask = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
cropNodeMask.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
cropNode.maskNode = cropNodeMask
self.addChild(cropNode)

// Create a container to hold the circle.
let container = SKNode()
cropNode.addChild(container)

// Create a blue circle and put it in the container.
let blueCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 110)
blueCircle.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
blueCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
container.addChild(blueCircle)
```

[image]

---

But a sprite in that same container seems to be cropped fine.

```
// Create a crope node with a small square.
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
let cropNodeMask = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
cropNodeMask.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
cropNode.maskNode = cropNodeMask
self.addChild(cropNode)

// Create a container to hold the sprite.
let container = SKNode()
cropNode.addChild(container)

// Create a spaceship and add it to the container.
let spaceshipNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
spaceshipNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
container.addChild(spaceshipNode)
```

[image]

Comment: Try something other than SKShapeNode, use SKLabelNode,  I can tell you SKShapeNode is bugged, that has been proven

Comment: Label is cropped correctly. So it's not the crop node -- it's the shape node that is broken.

Comment: Yes,  SKShapeNode has tons of bugs with it,  it is best to only use it to turn it into a texture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SKShapeNode is bugged,  best to avoid it at all costs.  Use it to create your shapes, then convert it to a texture for use with SKSpriteNode

Comment: Uh oh. Spoke too soon. I removed all SKShapeNodes from my project in favor of sprites and my content is still escaping the crop. I suspect it's when I have nested crop nodes, although I haven't boiled it down to a simple repro yet.

Comment: It looks like your answer is partially correct. SKCropNode and SKShapeNode interact poorly, but in this case it's definitely SKCropNode's fault because it also seems to fail with child SKCropNodes. Similar conclusion on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26558228/1181827).

Comment: SKCropNodes inside SKCropNodes produce a different result,  alpha transparent cropping( no longer becomes just a on off issue,  now if your alpha is 25% it will take that into account when cropping.  Has to do with the blending functions)

Comment: I'm using fully opaque or fully transparent pixels in my masks though. Blending shouldn't matter.

Comment: The math and functions still apply regardless if you use it or not